# unable to run flutter run after upgarding to flutter 2.8.0 from 2.5.3

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, flutter2.0

This is the error

> Running "flutter pub get" in inventory_controller...
> 6.2s Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering
> with "--enable-software-rendering". Launching lib/main.dart on Android
> SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
> ../../../Downloads/Programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/visibility_detector-0.2.0/lib/src/visibility_detector_layer.dart:276:21:
> Error: Too many positional arguments: 1 allowed, but 2 found. Try
> removing the extra positional arguments.
> super.addToScene(builder, layerOffset);
> ^
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Script '/home/bihire/Downloads/Programs/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle'
>   line: 1070
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
>
> > Process 'command '/home/bihire/Downloads/Programs/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with
> > non-zero exit value 1
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 40s Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> 41.9s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I did `flutter clean` ans `flutter pub cache repair` both without any success.

Is there anything else I should try?

Comment: Try updating the `visibility_detector` dependency to the latest version to see if it's fixed.

Comment: How do you update a package you don't have in your dependecy list again? @esentis

Answer (score 4):

Try to find out package that depends on this package and upgrade it version.
To find out package use in terminal: flutter pub deps

PS: i had to upgrade alice version in my case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: weirdly enough, I just upgraded again and It worked this time:)...thanks for the contribution though

Answer (score 1):

fixed it by updating `visibility_detector` to latest.

```yaml
visibility_detector: ^0.2.2
```